# Styles-m.css file locations

Tags: magento-2.1, css, less-css, styles

I am looking to change some css settings on my `Magento 2.1.8` store.

I understand that this file is created using `.less` files, but which less files is this made up of and where can i find them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deploying static view files, if you check this file:

> [your Magento install dir]/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/[vendor
>   name]/[theme name]/en_US/css/styles-m.less

inside you will see a list of all `.less` files that were used to create the final version of your `styles-m.css`.

For example, in Luma theme (**Magento 2.1.8**) the file is located here:
`/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.less`. Inside you can see the following list of files:

```
@import 'source/_reset.less';
@import '_styles.less';
@import (reference) 'source/_extends.less';

@import '../Magento_Braintree/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_CatalogEvent/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Multishipping/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Paypal/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_ProductVideo/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_SalesRule/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Weee/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_AdvancedCheckout/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_AdvancedSearch/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Bundle/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Catalog/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_CatalogSearch/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Customer/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_CustomerBalance/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Downloadable/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftCard/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftCardAccount/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftMessage/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftRegistry/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftWrapping/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_GroupedProduct/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Invitation/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_LayeredNavigation/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Msrp/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_MultipleWishlist/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Newsletter/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Review/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Reward/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Rma/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Sales/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_SendFriend/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Theme/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Vault/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Wishlist/css/source/_module.less';

@import 'source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_Banner/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_Catalog/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_CatalogEvent/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_Cms/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_GiftRegistry/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_MultipleWishlist/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_Reports/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_Sales/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_VersionsCms/css/source/_widgets.less';
@import '../Magento_AdvancedCheckout/css/source/_widgets.less';

@import 'source/lib/_responsive.less';

@media-target: 'mobile'; // Sets target device for this file

@import 'source/_theme.less';

@import 'source/_extend.less';
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for the file located here:-

> vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\styles-m.less

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using custom theme then file located on following path:**

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/web/css/styles-m.less

Answer (score -1):

Kindly review below link may be that will help you.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-less-and-the-chrome-devtools--net-36636

To change less file you need to install node js and grunt.

Kindly review below link for that.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html